# Can I rotate blue point for current location in my iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, mapping, ios6-maps

Hi I am working with Map view in iPhone, I am rotating mapview, it is correctly rotating. But My custom pin (imageview) is not rotating.

I run the Maps application in iPhone, in that app, 'v' shaped image for current location is appered and is rotating according to mapview rotation.

I used the below code for custom pin animation (rotation):

```
    // Setup the animation

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:2.0];
    //[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //--------For animating imageview ---------------------
    [annView addSubview:locaterImageView];
```

Can I rotate default pin in my custom apps?

Comment: Your pins should rotate automatically. Is there any rotation-related logic in your pin subclass?

Comment: yes, just i animated the imageview on annotation view, but it is not rotating

Comment: Some code would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but custom annotations do not rotate, just because the map does (and I understand, this is what you seek.)

However, I would recommend giving it a good thinking through, before moving on with this. Rotating map annotations is not everyones cup of tea UX-wise.